# How to distinct the foreignkey in django?

Tags: django

```
class Template(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=135, blank=True)
    pattern = models.ForeignKey(Pattern)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField()
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=135, blank=True)
```

I want to :

```
Template.objects.extra(where=[str]).order_by('create_time')
```

and according the foreignkey *'pattern'* to **distinct** the result.
How to do this? THX~

Comment: Have you tried `Template.objects.values('pattern').distinct()`

Comment: IIRC, Django doesn't do distinct, at least on MySQL.  You may need to use a custom manager.

Comment: @AamirAdnan In this way only get a map {pattern:id},but I want get the whole Pattern class.

Comment: @Kevin How to distinct a list whose elements are objects? THX

Comment: Forget about what you think the process should be. What do you want the result data look to like? do you need the list of all patterns that have a template? just the ids of all patterns that have a template? and why are you ordering by create_time?